# SSRS 2008 Negative Currency Values

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a column with negative currency values. I have changed the text box properties to display negative currency values as '-$##.##' but when I run the report the negative values still show up as (##.##). Any ideas on what is causing this or if there is a format string to fix the issue?

My code is:

```
Format(Sum(Fields!Column1.Value, "DataSet1"),"C2")
```

**EDIT:** I SOLVED IT The code below should work for anyone else with the issue.

```
Format(Sum(Fields!Column1.Value, "DataSet1"),"$#.00;-$#.00")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your Locale? For the U.S., the parenthesis seems to be the expected result for negative numbers for the C format.

> 123.456 ("C", en-US) -> $123.46
>
> 123.456 ("C", fr-FR) -> 123,46 €
>
> 123.456 ("C", ja-JP) -> ¥123
>
> -123.456 ("C3", en-US) -> ($123.456)
>
> -123.456 ("C3", fr-FR) -> -123,456 €
>
> -123.456 ("C3", ja-JP) -> -¥123.456

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: U.S. The parenthesis shouldn't be the expected result because I chagned the text box properties to display it as -$123.45 instead of (123.45), yet it was still displaying it as (123.45).

Comment: Sorry - I meant that the C format uses parenthesis for US currency.

Comment: No worries! So if I change the text box properties to display it a certain way, but use format(.....,"C2") does it ignore what I change the text box properties to?

Comment: The **FORMAT property** will take precedence over the Format function. The text box **expression** would be resolved first and then the **FORMAT property** would be applied to the expression result. I prefer to apply the formatting in the **FORMAT property** since it seems to export to Excel more accurately.